# Attempted to call an undefined method named "redirect" error in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

i have this error in my code and I have writing the "use" but i have this error:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "redirect" of class
>   "App\Controller\SetlocaleController".

My code:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class SetlocaleController extends HomeController {

    public function __construct(\Twig\Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    public function setLocaleAction(Request $request, $language = null)
    {
        if($language != null)
        {
            $session->set('_locale', $language);
        }

        $url = $request->headers->get('referer');
        if(empty($url))
        {
            return new response($this->twig->render('page/home.html.twig'));
        }
        else{
            return $this->redirect($url);
        }
    }
}
```

You have an  answer for me please ?

Comment: You use the method `$this->redirect()` but there's no such thing. It's not defined in your class, and presumably it's not defined in the parent class either.

Comment: is your `HomeController` extending from `AbstractController`?

Answer (score 1):

## Best practice solution

As proposed in the best practices for controllers documentation by Symfony, make sure you extend the Abstract controller on your controller.

```
// HomeController.php

// ...
class HomeController extends AbstractController {
// ...
```

No extra changes required to `SetlocaleController`. However if `RedirectResponse` is no longer used you can remove it's import
`use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;`

---

## Solution using HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse

You need to use the already imported `RedirectResponse` object. Do not use the code: `return $this->redirect($url);` since, as the error states, there is no `redirect(url)` function defined for your class.

```
return new RedirectResponse($url);
```

Comment: please  check if your HomeController extending from AbstractController to use  "$this->redirect()" helper

Comment: As ninjaTN says (and think,  I guess), it's better practice to use the helpers symfony provides. Check if you Controllers are extending `AbstractController`, If not add it, it will simplify your life later : [docs here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#the-base-controller-classes-services) [recommended/best practices here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html)

Comment: @Etshy I have updated the answer with the best practice solution. Thank you both for your input